# How to format curly braces for autoformat in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I hit alt-cmd-l to autoformat my code, it formats my imports and arrays from:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
let arr = [ myStringVar ]; // simple example, just go with it
```

to

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
let arr = [myStringVar];
```

How do I tell IntelliJ to put a space after the opening brace and before the close brace when auto-formatting?  (Specifically for javascript, typescript)

I've looked around for the answer and could not find one or asked the question badly. So I apologize if this is duplicate.

I'm on Intellij 2016.3.3

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Go to **preference**, select **Editor > Code Style > Javascript** and choose **Spaces**, check the checkboxes in **Within** section "**ES6 import/export brances**", and if you want spaces in object literal braces, check "**Object literal braces**" and as well.

Comment: In 2021, this is the most useful answer (object literal braces was specifically what I wanted/needed).  Thanks!!

Answer (score 12):

Go to settings and search for ES6 import/export braces. It should take you to Editor -> Code Style -> Javascript (or TypeScript). Just hit that checkbox on the spaces tab and it should add the spaces back.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using Angular, I believe you need to edit the settings for the **Typescript** and **NOT** for **JavaScript**. As I am using **IntelliJ IDEA 2021**, I will give you the fix for the same. You can do so by going through the following path:

1. Go to **File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > Typescript**
2. Click on the **Spaces** tab.
3. In the **Within** collapsible, tick the checkbox that says "**ES6 import/export braces**".
4. Click on **Apply** button and then click on **Ok** button.
5. If you now go to the Typescript file and hit the combo: **Ctrl + Alt + L**, it should now format the file correctly.

**CAVEAT:**

You have to be careful to ensure that you are making the changes for the Scheme that is applicable for your project. For example, maybe you have customized your Editor in some way previously and saved your customizations under a new name, such as **MyCustomSettings**. Once you do this, you will notice that there is an additional Scheme called the **Default** scheme. But **MyCustomSettings** will be your Scheme for your project and you have to make sure that you make the changes for the **MyCustomSettings** Scheme and not for the **Default** scheme. You can refer to the Schemes via the following path:
**File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > Typescript**,  there is a dropdown referred as Scheme. Choose the appropriate one for your Project and make sure you make the above edits in that Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is setting this pattern in `.editorconfig` file like this:

```
ij_javascript_spaces_within_imports = true
ij_typescript_spaces_within_imports = true
```