# How to automatically add a space before a curly brace in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

For example,

```
void print(){

}
```

I want a space automatically inserted before the "{":

```
void print() {

    }
```

In the Code Style settings, I can't find where to configure, but the examples seems to show that this is the default behavior in IntelliJ, but I can't see the effect. How to set this? Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a similar question and might fix your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903215/how-to-format-curly-braces-for-autoformat-in-intellij

Comment: Use Code | Reformat Code to apply the current code style. It's not enforced when you are just typing.

Comment: Is this can be set somewhere? otherwise, I always have to run "reformat code". I remember there is a setting somewhere.

Comment: There is no such setting, one can set [an option to reformat on closing the curly brace](http://i.imgur.com/3xPWRTU.png), but it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Does that mean a programmer needs to use reformat code whenever he writes code in IntelliJ, because {} is so common?

Comment: Use [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plug-in to reformat on save, it's also possible to reformat before commit.

Comment: Is it possible to install plugin in Intellij directly without downloading first?

Comment: Of course [it's possible](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151855/discussion-between-user697911-and-crazycoder).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plug-in to reformat on save. If there is in project CSV configured(for example git), it is possible to reformat only changed lines.

__

the answer is taken from comments